# Widgets on created window appear on parent window instead

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.5

I have a button that pops up an options window, when I try to populate the widgets on the new window they only appear on the parent window.

here is the related code:

```
from Tkinter import *
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        """builds main window."""
        windowAttr = {"width":450, "height":150}
        window = Frame(master, windowAttr).grid()
        btnAttr = {"text":"Options", "width":12, "height":1}
        self.btnOptions = Button(window, btnAttr, command=btnOptionsClick).place(x=360, y=5)

class Options:
    def __init__(self, optMaster):
        """Builds and displays the options window"""
        optAttr = {"width":300, "height":200}
        optWin = Frame(optMaster, optAttr).grid()
        self.chkMon = Checkbutton(optWin, text="Mon").place(x=50, y=50)

def btnOptionsClick():
    opt = Tk(className='Options')
    optionsApp = Options(opt)
    opt.mainloop()

root = Tk(className='Main Window')
app = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

chkMon appears on MainWindow and Options is always empty, I want chkMon to appear on Options and not on MainWindow.

I'm very new to python so I'm thankful for any help knowledgeable folks have.

edit:
I found a working solution, remove the Options class and change def btnOptionsClick() to:

```
def btnOptionsClick():
    opt = Toplevel(root, takefocus=True)
    chkMon = Checkbutton(opt, text="Mon").place(x=50, y=50)
```

Comment: Since you have a working solution, are you still looking for an answer or shall we close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the first line of your original btnOptionsClick() function be ...

```
opt = Toplevel()
```

and then leave the rest as it was.